# How to create Single.just(Void)

Tags: unit-testing, junit, java-8, rx-java, vert.x

I am writing some unit test cases for my application. I want to mock `MongoClient` `update` method, but the update returns `Single<Void>`.

```
when(mongoClient.rxUpdate(anyString(), any(JsonObject.class), any(JsonObject.class)))
.thenReturn(Single.just(Void))
```

Now `Single.just(Void)` doesn't work, what is the correct way of doing it?

---

--UPDATE--

So I am writing unit test for `updateUserProfile` method and for that I have mocked `service`. But the `service.updateAccount` method return is something I am not able to mock.

```
//Controller class
public void updateUserProfile(RoutingContext routingContext){
        // some code
    service.updateAccount(query, update)
            .subscribe(r -> routingContext.response().end());
}

//Service Class
public Single<Void> updateAccount(JsonObject query, JsonObject update){
    return mongoClient.rxUpdate("accounts", query, update);
}
```

Because the return type of `mongoClient.rxUpdate` is `Single<Void>`, I am not able to mock that part.

For now the workaround which I have figured out is:

```
public Single<Boolean> updateAccount(JsonObject query, JsonObject update){
    return mongoClient.rxUpdate("accounts", query, update).map(_void -> true);
}
```

But this is just a hacky way of doing it, I want to know how can I exactly create `Single<Void>`

Comment: why not use `Single.just(null)`?

Comment: Then it throws as null pointer exception

Comment: you are right. I forgot it.

Comment: you can try `Single.just((Void) new Object())`, since type erasure occurs in compiling time.

Comment: It still fails with the following exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Void`

Comment: A 2.x `Single<Void>` can't ever succeed as there is no non-null `Void` instance. Can you change the API to return `Completable` instead?

Comment: Its `Vertx` API, I cannot change that.

Comment: What exactly is this API? It may be worth reporting as bug.

Comment: 'null' is explicitly disallowed in RxJava2, and considered bad practice in RxJava1. If you care not about the result, use Completable instead of Single.

Comment: @MinatoNamikaze I'm sorry, you should try `Single.just(new Object())` instead, I used cast expression so the `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Comment: @holi-java `rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Void`

Comment: @MinatoNamikaze you have used `Single`? if it can't pass, there is a poor approach, `cotr = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]); cotr.setAccessible(true); Void instance = cotr.newInstance()`.

Comment: @MinatoNamikaze but wait, why did you mock `just(Void)`? only test subscribers are notified. you are one the way testing rxjava rather than your application. in your case you should write integrate-tests instead.

Comment: I am just mocking, it's not a true void method, it returns `Single` of type `Void`. I have updated my question with actual methods which I am trying to write unit test.

Comment: @MinatoNamikaze you should don't write unit test for `updateUserProfile`, instead you must write integrate tests for the service test against real external environment. only use mocks for unit tests that real environment can't produce easily, e.g: checking exception handling whether does as your thought.

Comment: In my case I ll have to write as its not just getting data from DB, it does some other stuff too. So I ll have to write UTs.

Comment: Can't you just change your service method signature from `public Single<Void> updateAccount(...)` to `public Completable updateAccount(...)`?

Comment: @Niall currently I am going ahead with that, but I wanted to know how to test void part.

Comment: @MinatoNamikaze I suspect the answer is that you can't. Void can't be constructed or extended, so there's no way to make an item of that type to return. I believe the issue is that it's not good practise to define the type as `Single<Void>` in the first place - if you don't want a return value, `Completable` is what you should use. `Single` implies that you want a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a method returning `Single<Void>` may raise some concerns, as some users have already expressed their view on this in the comments.

*But if you are stuck with this* and you really need to mock it (for whatever reason), there are definitely ways to create a `Single<Void>` instance, for example you could use the create method of the Single class:

```
Single<Void> singleVoid = Single.create(singleSubscriber -> {});

when(test.updateAccount(any(JsonObject.class), any(JsonObject.class))).thenReturn(singleVoid);

Single<Void> result = test.updateAccount(null, null);

result.subscribe(
        aVoid -> System.out.println("incoming!") // This won't be executed.
);
```

Please note: you won't be able to actually emmit a Single item, since Void can't be instantiated without reflection.

A trick that could eventually work in some cases is to ommit the generic type argument and emmit an Object instead, but this could lead easily to a ClassCastException. I would not recommend to use this:

```
Single singleObject = Single.just(new Object());

when(test.updateAccount(any(JsonObject.class), any(JsonObject.class))).thenReturn(singleObject);

Single<Void> result = test.updateAccount(null, null);

// This is going to throw an exception:
// "java.base/java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Void"
result.subscribe(
        aVoid -> System.out.println("incoming:" + aVoid)
);
```

And of course you could use reflection as well (as already suggested by Minato Namikaze):

```
Constructor<Void> constructor = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]);
constructor.setAccessible(true);
Void instance = constructor.newInstance();

Single<Void> singleVoidMock = Single.just(instance);

when(test.updateAccount(any(JsonObject.class), any(JsonObject.class))).thenReturn(singleVoidMock);

Single<Void> result = test.updateAccount(null, null);

result.subscribe(
        aVoid -> System.out.println("incoming:" + aVoid) // Prints: "incoming:java.lang.Void@4fb3ee4e"
);
```