# How to create a Mono<Void> that actually emits an element?

Tags: project-reactor, void

So I want to create a `Mono<Void>` (or any `Mono<SomeIgnorableType>`) that actually emits an element.
Why? Because I actually want to run an effect, and the result just implies the effect was run, YET, it can be ignored.

In Haskell Void is an uninhabitable type... like the `Nothing` in Scala. In Java Void is also uninhabitable, yet it is used more like the `Unit` type in Scala or the `()` (0 arity tuple) in Haskell. A type with only one inhabitant.

Ok, too much with the theory. My options so far:

1. `Mono.just((Void) null)` throws an Exception.
2. `Mono.empty().single()` (because I actually want to emit an event), ends up with failure, when one subscribes to it. And...
3. `Mono.just("something").then()` runs the effect, but then I cannot chain it with other monos, because it only emits complete and error events.

So how???

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556082/how-to-create-single-justvoid, which actually implies that this is not a reactor problem, more than a Java design problem. :facepalm: Java!

Comment: I'm actually starting to consider using `Mono<Tuple0>` (`Tuple0` from Vavr).

Comment: A void Mono is naturally empty. You can construct it with Mono.empty(). Why do you need it to have a value? Sometimes it´s useful to emit a value (e.g. to zip with another mono). In this case I wrap the value in an Optional. I suppose you could use Mono<Optional<Void>> in your case.

Comment: Exactly, I need it to emit a value to use FlatMap or Zip, or map or... Well, every method that needs a value on Mono.
I migrated to rxjava Single<Tuple0> eventually

Comment: For instance if you want to zip a void mono completion a with another mono b then you can rather use a.then(b). If you are using rxjava then you can use Completable

Answer (score 3):

Java's lack of null-safety means the unit type concept doesn't translate particularly well. I've never been convinced when people have postulated `Void` as equivalent to a unit type. You can never instantiate it by design; you can assume that any reference containing the `Void` type is `null`, which I don't really see as a value - it's more the absence of any value (ie. an uninhabitable type.)

There's nothing that I would consider a "real" unit type built into Java, but you can create one trivially via the use of an `enum` with a single value:

```
public enum Unit {UNIT}
```

If your `Mono` type is then set to `Unit`, this does what you need - you can either complete the `Mono` with no value, you can complete it with a single `Unit` value (and ignore the value, just reacting to the fact it's there), or complete it with an error. It sounds like that's exactly what you're after.

That said, answering the question directly and ignoring whether you *should* (you shouldn't IMHO), you *can* mock `Void` to actually assign it a non-null value. Mockito can do it no problem, you just need to make sure [Mockito is configured so it can mock final classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito):

```
Void v = Mockito.mock(Void.class);
Mono.just(v)
        .doOnNext(actualVoid -> System.out.println(actualVoid))
        .block();
```

Prints: `Mock for Void, hashCode: 1830745997`

(It's not something I've ever done, nor felt the need to do, but that doesn't prevent you from technically doing it.)

Comment: I ended up using the Tuple0 from vavr. I posted in the comments of the question my thoughts as I continued looking for solutions.
What you suggested was one of my options too